# What is the fastest way of copying a data from a DataWindow/DataStore to SQL Server table using Powerbuilder

Tags: sql-server, powerbuilder, datastore, datawindow

We have a datastore (**powerbuilder** datawindow's twin sister) that contains over **40.000 rows**, which takes more than **30 minutes** to insert into a **Microsoft SQL Server** table.

Currently, I am using a script generator that generates the sql table definition and an insert command for each row. At the end, the full script to sql server for execution.

I have already found that script generation process consumes more than **97%** of the whole task.

Could you please help me finding a more efficient way of copying my client's data to sql server table?

**Edit1** (after NoazDad's comments):

Before answer, please bear in mind that:

- Tabel structure is dynamic;
- I am trying to avoid using datastore.Update() method;

Comment: PB string processing native statements (`mid()`, `pos()`, concatenation, ...) are slow. That could explain that script generation takes 97% of the process. You could use the profiler to get optimization ideas.

Comment: Yes, you are right. PB string processing is indeed very slow. Thanks for you comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure it would be faster but you could save the data from the datastore in a tab delimited file then do a BULK INSERT via Sql.  Something like

BULK
INSERT CSVTest
FROM 'c:\csvtest.txt'
WITH
(
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
GO

You can try saving the datastore contents into a string variable via ds.object.datawindow.data syntax then save that to a file then execute the SQL.

Comment: Yes, that's the kind of approach I am looking for. However, I am wondering whether its limitations fit my usable scenarios. I will give it a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: this would be the fastest by far, otherwise you can use a pipeline object and set the commit factor to 1,000 or 5,000 rows so that you aren't doing commits every update (if the data will allow for that). But doing 40K inserts from a datawindow is going to be painful unless you have a system that lives on one server with no network lag. Matt has the right idea, save the file, and then have a process on the server that does a bulk load.

Comment: Just to add my two coins we are doing exactly that with various systems, on csv files having up to several millions rows.

Answer (score 2):

The way I read this, you're saying that the table that the data is being inserted into doesn't even exist in the schema until the user presses "GO" and initiates the script?  And then you create embedded SQL statements that create the table, and insert rows 1 by 1 in a loop?

That's...  Well, let's just say I wouldn't do it this way.

Do you not have any idea what the schema will look like ahead of time?  If you do, then paint the datastore against that table, and use ds_1.Update() to generate the INSERT statements.  Use the datawindow for what it's good for.

If that's not possible, and you must use embedded SQL, then at least perform a COMMIT every 1000 rows or so.  Otherwise, SQLServer is building up UNDO logs against the table, in case something goes wrong and they have to be rolled back.

Comment: Hi NoazDad! Thanks a lot for your comments. I forgot to mention that I am looking for a solution beside ds.Update() method. I will revise my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Other ideas...

- Disable triggers on the updated table while it is being updated (if possible)
- Use the PB Pipeline object, it has settings for commit-  might be faster but not much.
- Best idea. Do something on the server side. I'd try to create SQL statements for your 40K inserts, and call a stored procedure sending all 40k insert/update statements and let the stored procedure handle the inserts/updates.
- Create a dummy table with a few columns, one being a long text, update it with a block of SQL statements like mentioned in last idea and have a process that delimits and executes the sql statements.
- Some variant of above but using bulk insert as mentioned by Matt. Bulk insert is the fastest way to insert many rows.
- Maybe try something with autocommit so that you commit only at the end, or every 10k rows as mentioned by someone already.
- PB has an async option in the transaction object (connection) maybe you could let the update go in the background and let the user continue. This doesn't work with all databases and may not work in your situation. I haven't had much luck using async option.

The reason your process is so slow is that PB does each update separately, so you are hitting the network and database constantly. There may be triggers on the update table and those are getting hammered too. Slamming them in on the server eliminates network lag and is much faster. Using bulk load is ever faster yet because it doesn't run triggers and eliminates a lot of the database management overhead.

Expanding on the idea of sending SQL statements to a procedure, you can create the sql very easily by doing a dw_1.saveas( SQL! ) (syntax is not right) and send it to the server all at once. Let the server parse it and run the SQL.

Send something like this to the server via procedure, it should update pretty fast as it is only one statement:

```
Update TABLE set (col1, col2) values ('a', 'b')|Update TABLE set (col1, col2) values ('a', 'b')|Update TABLE set (col1, col2) values ('a', 'b')
```

In procedure:

Parse the sql statements, and run them. Easy peasy.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments. I am really targeted for something bulk-insert based or datawindow xml based, since inserts script string generation consumes most of execution.

Answer (score 1):

While Matt's answer is probably best, I have another option. (Options are good, right?)

I'm not sure why you're avoiding the datastore.Update() method. I'm assuming it's because the schema doesn't exist at the time of the update. If that's the only reason, it can still be used, thus eliminating 40,000 instances of string manipulation to generate valid SQL.

To do it, you would first create the table. Then, you would use datastore.SyntaxFromSQL() to create a datastore that's bound to the table. It might take a couple of Modify() statements to make the datastore update-able. Then you'd move the data from your original datastore to the update-able, bound datastore. (Look at RowsMove() or dot notation.) After that, an Update() statement generates all of your SQL without the overhead of string parsing and looping.

Comment: While your suggestion is indeed a valuable solution, I was look for a cutting Edge solution like Matt provided. Anyway, gave you a plus for the effort. Thanks